# Getting the HEX code of a colour within an image on hover / click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

Is it possible to get the hexadecimal code for a pixel within an image on a web page using jQuery, **without using the `canvas` element**? Please note, I do not want the background colour or colour of the div it is contained in, I want the actual colour code of the image.

For example:

Say you had an image contained within the div.

```
<div class="wrapper" style="background-color: red">
<img src="random/Image.png"/>
</div>
```

Say this random image has a transparent background and its contents is blue, purple and yellow, I want to get the blue posted back when I hover over the blue, same with the yellow if I hover over the yellow and same with the purple.

If that is possible, it would really help.

Comment: Without a `canvas` it is impossible, unless you have a server side script to look it up or print the values elsewhere and simply look them up.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use `canvas` to do it, and it would have to be an image URL that didn't violate Same Origin Policy.

Use `getImageData()` with the mouse coordinates to get the red, green, blue and alpha values for each pixel. You can then convert this to a hexadecimal string.